# Escape = character in wiki section title

Tags: mediawiki, wikitext

How to escape a "=" in a [wiki Section title](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aWiki_markup#Sections)? And more than one?

Some examples:

`=====` renders as a 2nd level title "=" (and not a first level "===").

`====` renders as "==" 1st level title (and not an empty 2nd level title).

How to make a === as first level title? This question is mainly driven by curiousity, since [escape documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aWiki_markup#Special_characters) deals only about the content or other characters than "=".

Comment: perhaps try <nowiki> ?

Comment: Nowiki works also, thanks mike

Comment: @Nemo, thanks for editing markup. I rejected the "wiki header title" edit because this question -and the accepted answer- are about the summary and the title in the content, not only the header/summary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separate with spaces, i.e. `== === ==`